# Gridview change row BackColor programmatically through a checkbox

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, colors, row

i am using VS 2010 C#
I have a DataGridView not to data source (colums are added manually) and each row has a check box which is should be always enabled.
When the user checked the checkbox, then it should do two things:

- enable the row of the gridview (the rest of columns, textboxs, combos,...)
- change the backcolor of the row to white (default is gray, like disabled)

i tried all provided codes and other solutions but there is no solution for any of the above mentioned requirements.
please help .!!
thanks alot

```
 private void dgv1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            Boolean Xcheckbox = (Boolean)dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            if (Xcheckbox == true)
            {
                dgv1.Rows[dgv1.CurrentRow.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                        
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < dgv1.Columns.Count-1; i++)
            {
                {
                    dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].ReadOnly = Xcheckbox;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Add an event to the checkbox within your row. 
Within the event then enable the rest of the columns, textboxes and combos and change the colour.
Post the code you already tried.

Comment: I posted the code which i use, but still not working, can you help please !! thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what have you tried yet ? please provide the code. M unable to comment on your question. You can add event to the check boxes and then pick the current row. Which will give you the right way to proceed.

**Update 2:**

You Can try THis

```
private void myDataGrid_OnCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == myCheckBoxColumn.Index && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        // Handle your checkbox state change here
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks alot !! . iwould like to vote the answer but i still have insufficient credit..but anyway thanks alot